# MS Access Sum and Averaging Columns with Same Information as New Column

Tags: ms-access, sum

So I have the following chart here where I have columns:

```
a b c d
1 1 1 3
1 1 1 4
1 1 1 5
2 2 2 1
2 2 2 3
2 2 2 3
3 3 3 4
3 3 3 5
3 3 3 6
```

What I want to do is add and average column d where columns a,b,c contain the same values. How would I go about doing this?

I imagine it would be something like

```
Select SUM(Table.d) where a = b AND b = c AS e
```

Comment: You can use the `AVG` function and don't need the `AS e` at the end of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select SUM(Table.d), AVG(Table.d) from Table Group by Table.a, Table.b, Table.c
```

Comment: Thanks figured it out, actually just with the sort by on the design view.